# WCF: An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Tags: wcf

A customer who is using our WCF based software is getting an error that indicates they are receiving an exception with the message "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" during a service call.

We are using a nettcp binding with message level authentication, and the client is a WPF application that keeps the channel open.

The customer claims that it will work fine for about 45 minutes before they run into the issue.  This is clearly not a clock skew issue or an authentication issue, so what are some other possibilities?

Comment: Have you verified if your firewall is blocking the access?

Comment: The customer claims that there is only a switch between the client and the service.

Also, the client makes a service call every five seconds.  So it's working fine for hundreds of consecutive calls, and then will fail with the above error.